# How to calculate year-over-year growth on monthly data for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
SeriesID    Year    Period  Employment
 ENU4800010010  2005      M04       9539195
 ENU4800010010  2005      M03       9467530
 ENU4800010010  2005      M02       9397395
 ENU4800010010  2005      M01       9329971
 ENU4800010010  2004      M04       9303133
 ENU4800010010  2004      M03       9253474
 ENU4800010010  2004      M02       9189497
 ENU4800010010  2004      M01       9133899
 ENU4800010010  2003      M04       9207635
 ENU4800010010  2003      M03       9191354
 ENU4800010010  2003      M02       9153461
 ENU4800010010  2003      M01       9117882
 ENU4800010010  2002      M04       9265141
 ENU4800010010  2002      M03       9255138
 ENU4800010010  2002      M02       9192597
 ENU4800010010  2002      M01       9139632
 ENU4800010110  2005      M04       182014
 ENU4800010110  2005      M03       181436
 ENU4800010110  2005      M02       181946
 ENU4800010110  2005      M01       181412
 ENU4800010110  2004      M04       181186
 ENU4800010110  2004      M03       179513
 ENU4800010110  2004      M02       179956
 ENU4800010110  2004      M01       179188
 ENU4800010110  2003      M04       181581
 ENU4800010110  2003      M03       181391
 ENU4800010110  2003      M02       181850
 ENU4800010110  2003      M01       181266
 ENU4800010110  2002      M04       177857
 ENU4800010110  2002      M03       177969
 ENU4800010110  2002      M02       177120
 ENU4800010110  2002      M01       177049
 ENU4800010151  2005      M04       117
 ENU4800010151  2005      M03       120
 ENU4800010151  2005      M02       121
 ENU4800010151  2005      M01       119
 ENU4800010151  2004      M04       120
 ENU4800010151  2004      M03       118
 ENU4800010151  2004      M02       117
 ENU4800010151  2004      M01       118
 ENU4800010151  2003      M04       126
 ENU4800010151  2003      M03       127
 ENU4800010151  2003      M02       131
 ENU4800010151  2003      M01       132
 ENU4800010151  2002      M04       130
 ENU4800010151  2002      M03       135
 ENU4800010151  2002      M02       138
 ENU4800010151  2002      M01       138
 ENU4800010152  2005      M04       1076
 ENU4800010152  2005      M03       1073
 ENU4800010152  2005      M02       1080
 ENU4800010152  2005      M01       1090
 ENU4800010152  2004      M04       1125
 ENU4800010152  2004      M03       1109
 ENU4800010152  2004      M02       1124
 ENU4800010152  2004      M01       1125
 ENU4800010152  2003      M04       1118
 ENU4800010152  2003      M03       1121
 ENU4800010152  2003      M02       1116
 ENU4800010152  2003      M01       1127
 ENU4800010152  2002      M04       1305
 ENU4800010152  2002      M03       1323
 ENU4800010152  2002      M02       1324
 ENU4800010152  2002      M01       1363
```

I have pasted a small chunk of the data I am dealing with for better understanding.
My question: I want to calculate the year-over-year growth rate for each series id (there are 4 series id given here). For example: for series id ENU4800010010 I want the growth rate between M01 2021 & M01 2020, M01 2020 & M01 2019..so on. Followed by M02 2021 & M02 2020..so on. I want to calculate this by group for each series id. I am having trouble in linking the month of one year to the same month of the other year. It will be really helpful if anyone can help me out coding this in python.

Kindly let me know if more info is required. Thanks in advance!

```
YoY = (BLS_data_compiled.groupby(['SeriesID'])['Employment'].pct_change(-1))
```

I tried this while I was dealing with annual data. But I am unable to replicate this for the monthly data.

Comment: Add a column for the previous year by subtracting one from the "year" column and `merge` the dataframe with itself joining SeriesID and period with the same values and joining year column with the "previous year" column. Now you have employment of year and last year of same period in one row and you can calculate the growth.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try what you suggested. Really appreciate your help :)